# pandas вывод по строкам

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Есть файл new.csv с таким содержимым

```
1 2 3 4;один
5 6 7 8;два
8 9 0 1;три
```

я вывожу содержимое первого столбика так

```
text = pd.read_csv('new.csv', header=None, delimiter=';')[[0]]
```

Подскажите, как правильно вывести первую строку первой колонки `1 2 3 4`

Comment: Если вы просто хотите посмотреть на данные, то можно `text.head(1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Подскажите, как правильно вывести первую строку первой колонки?

```
df = pd.read_csv('new.csv', header=None, sep=';')
print(df.iloc[0, 0])
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что  `ss=df.iloc[0,0]` уже не будет списком. Придётся разделять по пробелам?

Comment: @user, конечно, это просто строка. Не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать...

Comment: у меня этот массив идет дальше для перебора слов

Comment: @user, `этот массив идет дальше для перебора слов` и вы хотите ... ??

Comment: Спасибо, Вы направили меня)

Comment: @user, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) ;)